# Mapstruct: calling function from injected mapper

Tags: spring, mapstruct

I have a mapper like so:

```
    @Mapper(uses = {DateMapper.class, AuthenticationMapper.class})
    public interface LocalUserMapper {
        LocalUserMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(LocalUserMapper.class);

        @Mapping(target = "domains", source = "localUser.directDomains")
        @Mapping(target = "phone", source = "localUser.phoneNumber")
        @Mapping(target = "displayName", source = "localUser.displayPartyName")
        @Mapping(target = "authenticationMethod", expression =" java(mapAuthenticationMethodForLocalUser(localUser))")
        UserDTO convertLocalUser(LocalUser localUser);
}
```

to map the field "authenticationMethod" i want to do a few things locally, then let the AuthenticationMapper (see above) do the rest (note: I can't change the main mapping function of the AuthenticationMapper to suit my needs, it's used in other places)
ideally, use this function for mapping (as expression)

```
    default String mapAuthenticationMethodForLocalUser(LocalUser localUser) {
            AuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod = localUser.getAuthenticationMethod();
            if (localUser.useTwoLayerAuthentication()) {
// do some stuff and return something
            } //else
            return **authenticationMethodMapper**.convertAuthenticationMethod(authenticationMethod);
        }
```

this is not working as when the impl is generated authenticationMethodMapper is somehow unknown field

anyone know a good way to do this? thanks!